# Can std::atomic memory barriers be used to transfer non-atomic data between threads?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, stdatomic, memory-model

Is the following code standards compliant? (or can it be made compliant without making `x` atomic or `volatile`?)

This is similar to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680757/in-c11-can-stdatomic-be-used-to-transmit-non-atomic-data-between-two-thread), however I would like a citation to the relevant section of the C++ standard, please.

My concern is that atomic `store()` and `load()` do not provide sufficient compiler barriers for the non-atomic variables (`x` in the example below) to have correct release and acquire semantics.

My goal is to implement lock-free primitives, such as queues, that can transfer pointers to regular C++ data structures between threads.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int x; // regular variable, could be a complex data structure

std::atomic<int> flag { 0 };

void writer_thread() {
    x = 42;
    // release value x to reader thread
    flag.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
}

bool poll() {
    return (flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 1);
}

int main() {
    x = 0;

    std::thread t(writer_thread);

    // "reader thread" ...  
    // sleep-wait is just for the test.
    // production code calls poll() at specific points

    while (!poll())
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    t.join();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problems here. Can you go into more detail about what you suppose is unsafe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With acquire/release, yes, this will be enough. Relevant quotes (from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model)—as good as the standard in most cases):

> ### Memory Model
>
> When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting evaluations has a data race unless either
>
> - <s>both conflicting evaluations are atomic operations (see `std::atomic`)</s>
> - one of the conflicting evaluations **happens-before** another (see `std::memory_order`)
>
> ### std::memory_order
>
> #### Release-Acquire ordering
>
> If an atomic store in thread A is tagged `memory_order_release` and an atomic load in thread B from the same variable is tagged `memory_order_acquire`, all memory writes (non-atomic and relaxed atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B, that is, **once the atomic load is completed, thread B is guaranteed to see everything thread A wrote to memory.**