# Benefits & drawbacks of as-needed conditional std::atomic_thread_fence acquire?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

The code below shows two ways of acquiring shared state via an atomic flag. The reader thread calls `poll1()` or `poll2()` to check for whether the writer has signaled the flag.

Poll Option #1:

```
bool poll1() {
    return (flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 1);
}
```

Poll Option #2:

```
bool poll2() {
    int snapshot = flag.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (snapshot == 1) {
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that option #1 was [presented in an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254171/can-stdatomic-memory-barriers-be-used-to-transfer-non-atomic-data-between-thre/35254379#35254379), and option #2 is  similar to [example code at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence).

Assuming that the reader agrees to only examine the shared state if the `poll` function returns `true`, are the two `poll` functions both correct and equivalent?

Does option #2 have a standard name?

What are the benefits and drawbacks of each option?

Is option #2 likely to be more efficient in practice? Is it possible for it to be less efficient?

Here is a full working example:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int x; // regular variable, could be a complex data structure

std::atomic<int> flag { 0 };

void writer_thread() {
    x = 42;
    // release value x to reader thread
    flag.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
}

bool poll1() {
    return (flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 1);
}

bool poll2() {
    int snapshot = flag.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (snapshot == 1) {
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    x = 0;

    std::thread t(writer_thread);

    // "reader thread" ...  
    // sleep-wait is just for the test.
    // production code calls poll() at specific points

    while (!poll2()) // poll1() or poll2() here
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Option 2 looks awfully like "the double-checked locking anti-pattern", and if you use it, I would want to see lots of comments explaining why it isn't (probably with a link back here).  How much of a performance difference does poll2 make?  ('cos if the answer is "not much", I'd stick with poll1 on the KISS principle).

Comment: They look more or less the same to me. I'll echo Martin Bonner's sentiments, and also add that if you're interested in efficiency, well the easiest thing to do would be to profile!

Comment: @MartinBonner your concerns more-or-less match the motivation for the question. Side note: double-checked locking was only an anti-pattern prior to C++11: http://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/

Comment: Interesting article (in an interesting blog).

Comment: Heh, this looks a lot like a duplicate of a question I asked a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14167767/21475. Be sure to read the comments on it, lots of info in there. And in particular, Jeff Preshing's article linked in my update: http://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/

Comment: @Cameron thanks for the link. I understand that a fenced operation is not the same as a stand-alone fence. I don't think this is a duplicate question: my question revolves around putting `atomic_thread_fence` under the conditional, which is not a feature of your question.

Comment: @Ross: Ah, yes, I see. I skimmed too quickly, sorry, despite your question being better phrased than mine ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think I can answer most of your questions.

Both options are certainly correct, but they are not quite equivalent, due to the slightly broader applicability of stand-alone fences (they are equivalent in terms of what you want to accomplish, but the stand-alone fence could technically apply to other things as well -- imagine if this code is inlined). An example of how a stand-alone fence is different from a store/fetch fence is explained in [this post by Jeff Preshing](http://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/).

The check-then-fence pattern in option #2 does not have a name as far as I know. It's not uncommon, though.

In terms of performance, with my g++ 4.8.1 on x64 (Linux) the assembly generated by *both* options boils down to a single load instruction. This is hardly surprising given that x86(-64) loads and stores all have acquire and release semantics at the hardware level anyway (x86 is known for its quite strong memory model).

For ARM, though, where memory barriers compile down to actual individual instructions, the following output is produced (using [gcc.godbolt.com](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) with `-O3 -DNDEBUG`):

For `while (!poll1());`:

```
.L25:
    ldr     r0, [r2]
    movw    r3, #:lower16:.LANCHOR0
    dmb     sy
    movt    r3, #:upper16:.LANCHOR0
    cmp     r0, #1
    bne     .L25
```

For `while (!poll2());`:

```
.L29:
    ldr     r0, [r2]
    movw    r3, #:lower16:.LANCHOR0
    movt    r3, #:upper16:.LANCHOR0
    cmp     r0, #1
    bne     .L29
    dmb     sy
```

You can see that the only difference is where the synchronization instruction (`dmb`) is placed -- inside the loop for `poll1`, and after it for `poll2`. So `poll2` really is more efficient in this real-world case :-) (But read further on for why this might not matter if they're called in a loop to block until the flag changes.)

For ARM64, the output is different, because there are special load/store instructions that have barriers built-in (`ldar` -> load-acquire).

For `while (!poll1());`:

```
.L16:
    ldar    w0, [x1]
    cmp     w0, 1
    bne     .L16
```

For `while (!poll2());`:

```
.L24:
    ldr     w0, [x1]
    cmp     w0, 1
    bne     .L24
    dmb     ishld
```

Again, `poll2` leads to a loop with no barriers within it, and one outside, whereas `poll1` does a barrier each time through.

Now, which one is actually more performant requires running a benchmark, and unfortunately I don't have the setup for that. `poll1` and `poll2`, counter-intuitively,  may end up being equally efficient in this case, since spending extra time waiting for memory effects to propagate within the loop may not actually waste time if the flag variable is one of those effects that needs to propagate anyway (i.e. the total time taken until the loop exits may be the same even if individual (inlined) calls to `poll1` take longer than those to `poll2`). Of course, this is assuming a loop waiting for the flag to change -- individual calls to `poll1` *do* require more work than individual calls to `poll2`.

So, I think overall it's fairly safe to say that `poll2` should never be significantly less efficient than `poll1` and can often be faster, as long as the compiler can eliminate the branch when it's inlined (which seems to be the case for at least these three popular architectures).

My (slightly different) test code for reference:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>

int sharedState;
std::atomic<int> flag(0);

bool poll1() {
    return (flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 1);
}

bool poll2() {
    int snapshot = flag.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (snapshot == 1) {
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void __attribute__((noinline)) threadFunc()
{
    while (!poll2());
    std::printf("%d\n", sharedState);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::thread t(threadFunc);
    sharedState = argc;
    flag.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. This confirmed everything I _thought_ but didn't want to take the time to verify for a thorough answer. :-]